# count duplicates and non duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using MS Access SQL

Is it possible to;

1. list and count all duplicates in one field based on another field?
2. list all non duplicates in one field based on another field?

Example database below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your results, you just want a simple `group by`:

```
select name, year, count(*)
from [table]
group by name, year;
```

One statement cannot return two different headers.  I mean, you could run two queries:

```
select name, year, count(*) as NumDuplicates
from [table]
group by name, year
having count(*) > 1;

select name, year, count(*) as NumNonDuplicates
from [table]
group by name, year
having count(*) = 1;
```